# How to pack big negative long to binary string in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, int

I need to calculate `md5` hash of random `8` bytes long number, so I am trying to pack it:

```
import struct

num = 123L
bin = struct.pack( 'q', num )
```

which works fine, but, for big negative values:

```
num = -14710095416404972671L
bin = struct.pack( 'q', num )
```

I get this error:

```
struct.error: long too large to convert to int
```

from python 2.6

Which way I can convert it to use as input for md5 hash?

Comment: You seem to have an XY problem. Are you more concerned with getting a valid binary representation of `num`, or getting the md5 hash of `num`?

Comment: @RegularlyScheduledProgramming server side calculates md5 hash of binary representation of long in C++, I need to implement same hash in python.

Comment: I checked and sure enough I get different hashes using `struct.pack` vs `bin` in the hash, so I've deleted my answer. Maybe have a look at the source for the `struct` module? Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, that number just doesn't fit in an `8` byte long long (signed). The *maximum* value you *can* supply with `'q'` is  `-2 ** 63`, no less:

```
num = -2 ** 63 
bin = struct.pack('q', num )
```

while:

```
num = -2 ** 63 - 1
bin = struct.pack('q', num )
```

leads to `error: argument out of range`. That's the ceiling, with `'Q'` you can achieve larger positive (unsigned) values but with a limit there of `2 ** 64`.

Comment: I do not quite understand why that value which is `EB95EC9D994ED78D` does not fit into 8 bytes? Is that python limitation?

Comment: @Slava It fits if you use the format character for unsigned long longs `'Q'`. It won't if you use `'q'` which takes signed 8 byte numbers .

Comment: The problem that I get from C++ server value  `-14710095416404972671L` which represented there as `EB95EC9D994ED78D`, how do I make last from the first?

Comment: @Slava The value `-14710095416404972671` is represented in hex as `-0xcc24c1d802eb947f` not `EB95EC9D994ED78D`. `EB95EC9D994ED78D` is `-16975734532069054349`.

Comment: You are right, I was confused by windows calculator damn

Answer (score 1):

You have a variety of choices, as soon as you realise MD5 operates on any byte stream. It is important to note that sign does not matter for MD5; it does not interpret integers, it manipulates a stream. Therefore you don't need to care about the sign of your input or converting to signed integers. You need a byte array, which you can obtain in multiple ways, my preference is:

```
In [30]: 0xEB95EC9D994ED78D.to_bytes(8, 'big')
Out[30]: b'\xeb\x95\xec\x9d\x99N\xd7\x8d'
```

which will handle arbitrary integers within the limits Python's integers allow.